# Probability of an element getting selected where we have to select K elements out of N elements

Tags: probability

I was reading about **Reservoir Sampling** and in the article it was mentioned

> To prove that this solution works perfectly, we must prove that the probability that any item stream[i] where $0 \le i < n$ will be in final reservoir[] is $k/n$.

Actually I want to get proof of why **Reservoir Sampling** works but I couldn't understand how Probability of an element getting selected where we have to select $K$ elements out of $N$ elements is $K/N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the particular element is selected when we select $k$ of the $n$ elements, we must also select $k - 1$ of the other $n - 1$ elements.  Hence, the probability that the particular element is selected is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{n - 1}{k - 1}}{\dbinom{n}{k}} & = \frac{\dbinom{n - 1}{k - 1}}{\dbinom{n}{k}}\\
& = \frac{\dfrac{(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)![(n - 1) - (k - 1)]!}}{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}}\\[2 mm] 
& = \frac{\dfrac{(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)!(n - k)!}}{\dfrac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)!(n - k)!} \cdot \frac{k!(n - k)!}{n!}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{(n - 1)!k!}{(k - 1)!n!}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{(n - 1)!k(k - 1)!}{(k - 1)!n(n - 1)!}\\[2 mm]
& = \frac{k}{n}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for this explanation

Answer (score 0):

You split a group of N elements into 2 groups, K and N-K elements.
What is the probability of a specific element to be in group 1 if it is not K/N ?